# VB number representation is strange, how do i convert it to a natural number

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, vb.net, vb.net-to-c#

So this may be obvious but i have recently inherited some legacy code and scattered around the code are array indexes like this

```
someArray(&H7D0)
```

I get that this "&H7D0" is the index but how do i go about changing it to a real number as i am converting the code to C#.

the code is a mess and it's not obvious what it might be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [Hexidecimal number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal). The equivalent C# would be `someArray(0x7d0)`

Both are equivalent to the decimal number `2000` so you could actually write `someArray(2000)` to allow the code to be used in both languages.